# PostgreSQL, how to resolve multiple row errors returned by a subquery used as expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, correlated-subquery

I'm trying to output rows consisting of a value and a list of names. This is my query:

```
Update person set institution_v2 = (select dv.entity_id 
from dictionary_v2 dv
left join dictionary_entry_v2 dev on dev.dictionary_id = dv.id
left join person p on p.name = dev.entry_value 
JOIN journal_person_relation jpr on jpr.person_id = p.person_id 
JOIN journal j on jpr.journal_id = j.journal_id)
```

But it fails with:
**SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression**

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Use a subselect that returns only a single row. How that has to look depends on what you want to do.

Comment: is the person within the subquery supposed to be the same as the updated person ? in that case don't repeat the join but reuse the person in a where clause.

Comment: "I'm trying to output rows consisting of a value and a list of names." but you show an update statement which updates the institution_v2 field for every person record in your table. You will have to provide more information otherwise the most useful comment you get will be the one of @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: These two LEFT joins essentially reduce your subquery to `(select dv.entity_id 
from dictionary_v2 dv` (or: worse)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you intend a *correlated* subquery.  So, don't re-use `person` in the subuqery:

```
update person p
    set institution_v2 = (select dv.entity_id 
                          from dictionary_v2 dv join
                               dictionary_entry_v2 dev 
                               on dev.dictionary_id = dv.id
                          where p.name = dev.entry_value 
                         );
```

Note:  This *could* still return duplicates.  It is possible that a single value is not appropriate for the column -- perhaps you want an array -- or if an arbitrary matching value works, use `limit 1`.
I don't think the journal tables are adding anything to the logic.